# Extract bucket name from aws s3 url using regex

Tags: regex, go, amazon-s3

I want to extract the bucket name from AWS s3 URLs.

URLs can be in many formats. Below is the list of regex for supported s3 URLs:

```
[a-z0-9.-]+\.s3\.amazonaws\.com
[a-z0-9.-]+\.s3-[a-z0-9-]+\.amazonaws\.com
[a-z0-9.-]+\.s3\.[a-z0-9-]+\.amazonaws\.com
[a-z0-9.-]+\.s3-website[.-](eu|ap|us|ca|sa|cn)
```

Example:

```
bucket-name.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
bucket.name.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
bucket.name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com
bucket.name.s3.amazonaws.com
```

I want a single regex that can extract `bucket-name` from these URLs in `GoLang`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
^(.+)(?:\.s3[-.].*)$
```

Translated:

> From the beginning of the string find everything leading up to `.s3.` or `.s3-` and capture it into group #1.

Your bucket name will be in `$1`.

See the regex101 link below and use the code generator to see a Golang example.

https://regex101.com/r/LRvA5F/1

Comment: Look at the regex I have provided for s3 URLs. Bucket name can also have dots.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat You should add the appropriate examples.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat If Amazon has provided the regex then why did you ask the question. Are you looking to learn how to use it in a specific programming language?

Comment: added appropriate examples.

Comment: I have list of urls, shown in example. And I want to extract bucket name out of them. And I need a regex that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```golang
^(.*?)\.s3\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/rjulTV/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s3                       's3'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

[Go code sample](https://play.golang.org/p/dk7_kp-HPY_W):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*?)\.s3\b`)
    str := "bucket-name.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    match := r.FindStringSubmatch(str)
        fmt.Println(match[1])
}
```